# Moving function from one controller to another controller in symfony

Tags: symfony

I wrote a function in DemoController.

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction() {
    return somethng_response;
}
```

Now I want to shift this to DefaultController inside AppBundle. I just moved these things into that controller but I'm getting the below error

```
FileLoaderImportCircularReferenceException in FileLoader.php line 97: Circular reference detected in "D:\myProj\app/config/routing_dev.yml" ("D:\myProj\app/config/routing_dev.yml" > "D:\myProj\app/config\routing.yml" > "D:\myProj\src\AppBundle/Controller/" > "D:\myProj\app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

## routing_dev.yml

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml

# AcmeDemoBundle routes (to be removed)
_acme_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

## routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: Paste here your `routing_dev.yml` and `routing.yml`... And if you have some routing configuration in your Bundle, paste it here too.

Comment: There's something wrong in your DefaultController... Can you paste it, please?